# md5 module error

Tags: python, module, md5, ply

I'm using an older version of PLY that uses the md5 module (among others):

```
import re, types, sys, cStringIO, md5, os.path
```

... although the script runs but not without this error:

```
DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
```

How do I fix it so the error goes away?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Q: How do I fix it so the error goes away?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use sha1 instead of md5? md5 usage is not recommended.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the warning message is quite straightforward. You need to:

```
from hashlib import md5
```

or you can use python < 2.5, http://docs.python.org/library/md5.html

Comment: Tried that already, but it breaks the script then. AttributeError: "'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'new'"

Comment: well, then the 2 md5 are not the same thing, you may need to 1) rewrite the old code, 2) use python < 2.5, or 3) ignore the warning.

Comment: @3zzy you have something like `import md5; md5.new(data).hexdigest()`, make it `from hashlib import md5; md5(data).hexdigest()`. Old stuff but I bumped into the same error.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error, that's a warning.

If you still insist on getting rid of it then modify the code so that it uses [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the warning can be silenced.  And hashlib.md5(my_string) should do the same as md5.md5(my_string).

```
>>> import md5
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
>>> import hashlib
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> m = md5.new(s)
>>> print s, m.hexdigest()
abc 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
>>> m = hashlib.md5(s)
>>> print s, m.hexdigest()
abc 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
>>> md5(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>> md5.md5(s)
<md5 HASH object @ 0x100493260>
>>> m = md5.md5(s)
>>> print s, m.hexdigest()
abc 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
```

As @Dyno Fu says:  you may need to track down what your code actually calls from md5.

Answer (score 0):

please see the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html) , 28.5.3 gives you a way to suppress deprecate warnings. Or on the command line when you run your script, issue `-W ignore::DeprecationWarning`

Answer (score 0):

i think the warning is ok,still you can use the md5 module,or else hashlib module contains md5 class

```
import hashlib
a=hashlib.md5("foo")
print a.hexdigest()
```

this would print the md5 checksum of the string "foo"

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
try:
    import warnings
    warnings.catch_warnings()
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    import md5
except ImportError as imp_err:
    raise type(imp_err), type(imp_err)("{0}{1}".format(
        imp_err.message,"Custom import message"))
```